# Extending a colorbox on the footnote

Tags: minipage, colorbox, parbox

In the middle of my book document, I would like to add a page like a title-page. This page is half white and half light blue, with some information in the two halves. Header and footnotes are maintained as any other page of the main matter.

Up to now, I was able to prepare something like this, taking a look to other similar answers:

[image: The tentative page that I have created]

with the code

```
    \documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,dvipsnames]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % Language dictionary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Typefont enconding
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Standard Latex fonts (but better visualization)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Headers and footnotes
\usepackage{pdfpages}           % To add pages from other documents and more

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

% font for the header
\newcommand{\helv}{%
    \color{gray}\fontfamily{phv}\slshape\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear previous fancy styles
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\helv \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\helv \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% plain style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\helv \thepage}
}
%%% End of HEADER AND FOOTER DESCRIPTION

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[6-10]

\cleardoublepage
% definition of colors
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,201,201}
\colorlet{mylightblue}{myblue!30}
\vspace*{10cm}
        \begin{flushright}
            \textbf{\Large A very nice title}\\
            \textbf{\Large of a very interesting article}\\
            \textbf{\Large that I will embed in this report}
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace*{-10pt}
\par\medskip
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth+0.7in][c]{%
    \colorbox{mylightblue}{%
        \parbox{\paperwidth}{%
        \raisebox{3in}{%
            \hspace*{\dimexpr\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}%
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright}
                    {\large Author 1, Author 2, Author 3} \\
                    {\large \textit{Journal of Research Magazines}, Vol. 1, pp. 1-12, (2017).}
                \end{flushright}  
                \vfill
            \end{minipage}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}\par\medskip

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

I would like to extend the lightblue color on the whole bottom part of the page, including the footnote part. I tried by using raisebox, but at some point the whole colorbox moves to the next page. Also, I would like to avoid Tikz and, additionally, this has to be made only on certain pages of the document, not all.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would certainly use tikz and tikzmark but beside this:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,dvipsnames]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % Language dictionary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Typefont enconding
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Standard Latex fonts (but better visualization)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % Headers and footnotes
\usepackage{pdfpages}           % To add pages from other documents and more

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

% font for the header
\newcommand{\helv}{%
    \color{gray}\fontfamily{phv}\slshape\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} %clear previous fancy styles
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\helv \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\helv \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
% plain style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhead{} % get rid of headers
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\helv \thepage}
}
%%% End of HEADER AND FOOTER DESCRIPTION

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\lipsum[6-10]

\cleardoublepage
% definition of colors
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,201,201}
\colorlet{mylightblue}{myblue!30}
\vspace*{10cm}
        \begin{flushright}
            \textbf{\Large A very nice title}\\
            \textbf{\Large of a very interesting article}\\
            \textbf{\Large that I will embed in this report}
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace*{-10pt}
\par\medskip
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth+0.7in][c]{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \colorbox{mylightblue}{%
        \parbox[t]{\paperwidth}{%
        {%
            \hspace*{\dimexpr\hoffset+\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}%
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright}
                    {\large Author 1, Author 2, Author 3} \\
                    {\large \textit{Journal of Research Magazines}, Vol. 1, pp. 1-12, (2017).}
                \end{flushright}

                \rule{0pt}{15cm}
            \end{minipage}%
            }%
        }%
    }}%
}\par\medskip

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't have time, but why not eso-pic, BG image, rule?

Comment: @KeksDose: Would work certainly too -- if really the half of the page should be in blue.